# Leaflet Search: How to auto-zoom to found feature?

Tags: leaflet, zooming, qgis

- Hey ! : )

Still quite new to the world of GIS and Leaflet in particular.
I implemented a search field with the Leaflet Search Plugin (https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search).

It's finally working, incl. marking the found feature and bringing it to the center of the map.
I would now like to add a suitable zoom-level, so that the found feature is easily to identify and not within a cloud of other points.

I hope you understand the issue and can help me to find a solution to this.
If you need any further details, please let me know!

Thanks in advance,
Tarek

I did not try anything serious yet, as I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 0):

When you initiate the L.control.search - you can specify the zoom level when centering markers in the options.

https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#options

```js
const search = L.control.search({
layer: layer-to-search-in,
propertyName: 'property-of-layer-to-search-for',
zoom: integer-for-your-preferred-level-of-zoom
}).addTo(map)
```